# Primes congruent to {0,2} modulo 3 and the greatest common divisor of $2s(s-1)$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, congruences, gcd-and-lcm

This problem is related to the question asked here: [The primes $s$ of the form $6m+1$ and the greatest common divisor of $2s(s-1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1700909/the-primes-s-of-the-form-6m1-and-the-greatest-common-divisor-of-2ss-1)

I would like to prove the following. If $s$ is prime Let $\psi(s) = 2s(s-1)$. I write $(\psi(s),\psi(s+2))$ to be the greatest common divisor of $\psi(s)$ and $\psi(s+2)$. Then

$ (\psi(s),\psi(s+2))= \begin{cases} 4 &\mbox{if } s \equiv \{0,2\} \pmod{3} \\ 
12 & \mbox{if } s = 6m+1 \end{cases}.$

The case equal to 12 has already been shown. Suppose that $s$ is congruent to $0$ or $2$ modulo $3$. If $s=3$ then $(\psi(3), \psi(5)) = (12,40) = 4$. With the exception of $3$ I am thinking we can write every other $s$ as $3n-1$ for some positive integer $n$. Then $\psi(s+2) =\psi(3n-1+2) = \psi(3n+1)$. So we are computing $((\psi(3n-1),\psi(3n+1))$? Is this the right approach?

Comment: All your steps are correct. Note that you've used the fact that there's only one prime congruent to $0$ mod $3$. That is $3$ itself. However, I would say your approach can be more straightforward. The top level strategy: First show that $4$ divides both numbers- this can be done by congruences mod $2$. Then show that nothing else divides them: this can be done with the rule for gcd, that $(a, b) = (a + b, b)$.

Comment: You wrote "First show that 4 divides both numbers". Do you mean $4|\psi(s)$ and $4|\psi(s+2)$?